# How to show model and list View ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I followed this tutorial for creating first ASP.NET MVC project:
[Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

(In this example it's about movies, but I want to create store)
So after all steps everything works fine (CRUD operations, searching, etc...)

But now I want to create table which will show products added to cart...

This is my model:

```
namespace TypeqastShopProject.Models
{
    public class ProductModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

This is my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<TypeqastShopProject.Models.ProductModel>

<h1>All products</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<form asp-controller="Products" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <p>
        Title: <input type="text" name="SearchString" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
</form>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a> |
                    <asp:Button onclick="Button1_Click" ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save"
                                OnClientClick="return countclickofButton();" />
                    @*<a asp-action="AddToCart" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Add to cart</a>*@
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<h4>Cart</h4>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
            </th>
            <th>
                Amount
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.ToList())
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And This is my controller:

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private readonly MvcTypeqastShopContext _context;

    public ProductsController(MvcTypeqastShopContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
    {
        var products = from p in _context.Product
                       select p;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            products = products.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString));
        }

        return View(await products.ToListAsync());
    }
```

So as you can see I want to show two tables on the page.
First one is table populated from database with all available products, and the second table should be populeted by user, by clicking on the button 'add to cart'.

My question is what would be best practice and how to bind list to .cshtml view?

Answer (score 0):

Can use Ajax to reload list after click add to cart.

Comment: Tran Anh Hien 
Good.  But how?

Comment: Can refer link: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/using-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc